# Is there a memory-efficient way to use a tuple to iterate over very large os.scandir() objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, copy, scandir

**EDITED TO FOCUS ON FILENAME (PARTIAL) MATCHING:
I am working with approximately 1.8 million files in one directory on a remote server. I am using os.scandir() in python3 to generate the full list of files in that directory, then checking each file name against an existing tuple, and, if there is a match, copying that file to a separate directory (also on the remote server).

The tuple I am using to check for the proper filenames is ~100,000 items long. Further, each item in the tuple is only a partial match for the actual filename -- for example, a tuple item might be '2019007432' and I want it to match a filename such as '2019007432_longunpredictablefilename.doc'. So I've used .startswith when searching filenames, rather than looking for exact matches.

I have successfully been able to run this code one time, but the script slows down progressively as it goes on, maxing out my computer's RAM -- and it took about 24 hours to run. As I will be adding to the 1.8 million files in the future, and I may have additional (longer) tuples with which to find and copy files, I'm looking for ways to streamline the code so it will run more efficiently. Does anyone have any suggestions about how to make this work any better?

```
import os
import shutil
from variables import file_tuple

srcpath = 'path/to/source/directory'
destpath = 'path/to/destination/directory'

counter = 1
copy_counter = 1
error_list = []

all_files = os.scandir(srcpath)


for file in all_files:
    try:
        if file.name.startswith(file_tuple):
            shutil.copy(srcpath + '/' + file.name, destpath)
            print('copied ' + str(counter) + ' -- ' + str(copy_counter))
            copy_counter +=1
        else:
            if counter % 5000 == 0:
                percent = "{0:.0%}".format(counter/1860000)
                print(str(counter) + ' -- ' + str(percent))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        error_list.append(file.name)
    counter +=1
        
print(error_list)
```

Comment: Why do you need to create a list out of it? Batching doesn't make sense if you are going to do that, then it takes even more memory. Just iterate over it directly?

Comment: Yes, I wasn't saying that the list/batching is the right answer, just trying to show what I had already tried to speed it up.  But since it hangs on the list part, it's clearly the wrong approach!

Comment: Ok, but again, *why are you using `list` at all?* Why not iterate directly?

Comment: I have now edited the code in the post to make it clearer -- I did first just iterate directly, but that took 24 hours and ran progressively more slowly over time.  I then tried batching, but as you pointed out, that is not a good solution.  I am looking for a fix to the original code, that does not contain a list or batching, that will have it run more efficiently.

Comment: So, there's *nothing* you can say about the structure of the file-names, like, for example, if they always start with `XXXXXX_somethingrandom`, then you could split on `'_'` and use the first part to check in a set of strings.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga great, yes, they do all start with XXXXXX_, so I can split on '_', and then use that to check against the list of partial filenames, which I will convert to a set.  I've never used a set before, and didn't know they existed.  I just looked it up and it seems that, as you said, sets are much better than tuples for very large files. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So now we talk about algorithm. In my opinion one of the best idea is to shrink the list of all files in the computer. So try to find a similar patter for this names in tuple like all start with a digit or all ends with a digit or contains only digits or have some precise length range. After you subset this files you could look across much smaller list. Still it will be a O(N^2) although it might be significantly more efficient. * It is like one additional loop across all files looking for similar pattern

Comment: Thank you -- I am not very familiar with bash -- from what I understand the above is iterating over the file tuple and finding matching entries in the directory, thene copying them. But I don't understand how the 'pattern*' part works . . .  Right now, my file tuple is about 100,000 items long -- how can i use 'pattern*' to refer to that tuple?

Comment: @jbat "Right now, my file tuple is about 100,000 items long" well there's your problem... `.startswith` is going to be O(N) on the length of that tuple, and thus it's going to be polynomial time. *That's* your problem, not the original quesiton you asked, which is how to iterate over the results of scandir in a memory efficient manner. You should elaborate on *that*. This is a classic X-Y problem.

Comment: Great, I had no idea that this was the source of the problem.  If that's the case -- that the actual problem is that the tuple is so long, and is not iterating over the scandir result -- is there another way for me to be doing this copy process that makes sense? Ultimately, I need to find all the files that have names matching what's in the tuple and copy them elsewhere, but I'm more than happy to construct all of this in a manner that is more efficient that what I've laid out here.

Comment: @jbat can you edit your question and add specific details about what you are trying to do? So, if for example, you are looking for exact matches, then just use a `set` instead of a tuple, and check `file.name in set_of_file_names` instead of `file.name.startswith(tuple_of_file_names)`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you so much for your continued help.   I just edited the question to hopefully make it clearer.  Unfortunately, I'm not looking for exact matches.

Comment: So it is more about algorithm, I updated my answer.

Comment: @polkas  so if I just break down the tuple list down into smaller lists, and run them separately, that will be faster?  that is a much easier task than trying to work with scandir and all the files I have to search through!

Answer (score 0):

In case this ends up being useful to others: Following the advice from @juanpa.arrivillaga, I converted my tuple into a set, and altered my code to split my the filenames generated by scandir such that they would be an exact match with the items in the set. This ran in about 6 hours (compared to 24+ hours the original way. See code below.

I haven't yet tried @polkas suggestion, which is to break down the tuple into smaller chunks and run them separately, but I suspect it will be very useful for a) unstable internet connections, to allow me to only run sections at a time without losing my place when the internet drops and/or b) when the filenames cannot be easily split at a known character.

```
files = os.scandir(srcpath)
for file in files:
    try:
        UID = file.name.split("_")[0]
        if UID in file_set:
            shutil.copy(srcpath + '/' + file.name, destpath)
            print('copied ' + str(counter) + ' -- ' + str(copy_counter))
            copy_counter +=1
        else:
            if counter % 5000 == 0:
                percent = "{0:.0%}".format(counter/1860000)
                print(str(counter) + ' -- ' + str(percent))
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error on line {}'.format(sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno), type(e).__name__, e)
        error_list.append(file.name)
    counter +=1
print(error_list)
```